# how to make checkbox works with an input field individually

Tags: javascript

How to enable input field by selecting checkbox?

This code enable all input fields but how to enable one by one by checking corresponding checkbox

```js
var getInput = document.getElementsByClassName("test"),
    changeState = document.getElementsByClassName("check");


Array.from(changeState).forEach(function(checkBox){
    checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(){
        Array.from(getInput).forEach(function(inputText){
            if(inputText.disabled == true){
                inputText.disabled = false;
            }else{
                inputText.disabled = true;
            }
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<form id="contact">
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following code.

```js
var getInput = document.getElementsByClassName("test"),
    changeState = document.getElementsByClassName("check");


Array.from(changeState).forEach(function(checkBox){
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(event){
    var inputText = event.target.parentElement.firstElementChild;
    if (inputText.disabled == true) {
        inputText.disabled = false;
    } else {
        inputText.disabled = true;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<form id="contact">
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: While your answer solves the problem. It is advisable to mention what changes you made and why you made them (or to explain your answer a bit). So that the OP can understand what was the problem in their code.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the change event callback function the parameter **e** you can find out which element caused the event using **e.target**.

If we take a look at the hierarchy of your html elements we can see that the input text field is the html element before the checkbox. So to get there, we have to use **e.target.parentNode** to get to the paragraph element. Now we can use  **e.target.parentNode.children** to get a html collection of childrens of the paragraph but since we know it's the first one we can simply use **e.target.parentNode.children[0]** to get to the input element.

```js
var getInput = document.getElementsByClassName("test"),
  changeState = document.getElementsByClassName("check");


Array.from(changeState).forEach(function(checkBox) {
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var input = e.target.parentNode.children[0];
    if (input.disabled == true) {
      input.disabled = false;
    } else {
      input.disabled = true;
    }

  })
});
```

```html
<form id="contact">
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    e.target.parentNode.children[0].disabled= !e.target.checked;    
})
```

```js
var getInput = document.getElementsByClassName("test"),
    changeState = document.getElementsByClassName("check");


Array.from(changeState).forEach(function(checkBox){
    checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(e){
        e.target.parentNode.children[0].disabled= !e.target.checked;     
    })
});
```

```html
<form id="contact">
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that condition `if (inputText.disabled == true)` isn't quite correct because may lead to unpredictable behavior.

Rather It should check whether checkbox checked or not.

Also it should select child element `input` of parent node. So `.parentElement.querySelector('input')` will select input element despite its position.

Let say if checkbox will stand before input field, then `.parentElement.children[0]` will select wrong element.

```js
var changeState = document.getElementsByClassName("check");

[...changeState].forEach(function(checkBox){
    checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(){
        let inp = this.parentElement.querySelector('input');
        inp.disabled = !this.checked;
    })
});
```

```html
<form id="contact">
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="test" disabled>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
        </p>
</form>
```